# "In / how many percents is it smaller"?

Tags: sentence-construction, interrogatives

If I have two apples, one is smaller (/bigger) than the second. What's the way to ask about the differences between them in percents?

Could it be correct to say

> 1)  "In how many percents is this one smaller than the second?"

Or simply I should omit the preposition (in) and ask:

> 2)  "How many percents is this one smaller than the second?"

Or maybe neither work here and an other way that I didn't mention is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not correct English to ask **how many percents**. **Per cent** means per hundred and you can't really ask **how many per hundreds is something**.

The easiest way to ask is: **In percentage terms, how much smaller/bigger is this apple than that?**

You could also ask: **What percentage smaller/bigger is this apple than that?**

You could make it more complicated and ask: **What percentage is this apple of that?** but people don't speak like that and might be a bit surprised if you asked them in that fashion.

Comment: Additionally, it would be wrong to ask "What percentage is this apple of that?" because that implies the one apple is a subset of the other.  

Also percentage difference is directional.  80 is 20% smaller than 100, but 100 is 25% greater than 80.  100 -20% = 80 but 80+20% = 96

Comment: "How many percent smaller?" works for me (but maybe not in formal writing).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Iv'e learnt something new today:) what's a about "By how much percent is this bigger than that"? (It something usually I need for formal writing as an question. While if I'm not mistaken your suggestions are for spoken language. Isn't it?)